# How to sign in XPI file without use of Mozilla data store

Tags: firefox-addon, xpi

We are signing xpi file using verisign certificate using NSS signtool.

However this involves following steps

1. export verisign pfx file to mozilla firefox
2. Import this exported certificate into .crt extension
3. Now export, verisign certificate in pkcs12 format from mozilla
   firefox datastore
4. Now signin the xpi extension using pkcs12 format

We want to avoid step 3, if somehow we can convert pfx file to pkcs12 file, so we can automate the entire process.

Please help if someone knows this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're getting at, but e.g. OpenSSL has command line tools to convert certs, etc. between formats.
Also, since you'll likely be using the same cert for a period of time, it would be easy to setup a store for signtool once, just like the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Signing_a_XPI) suggests.

Also a shameless plug - Signing XPIs without NSS signtool: http://nmaier.github.io/xpisign.py/